# The Housing Estate

Tags: mathematics, construction

A constructor wishes to build a housing estate in a square terrain with 64 (8 x 8) smaller plots of land, at most one house to a plot. Local urban rules allow building a house in a plot only if at least half of the neighboring plots (within the development) are destined for parks.

**What is the largest number of houses the constructor can build if he is to comply with the local rules?**

In another, smaller terrain (6 x 6), another constructor built 22 houses complying with the same rules:

[image]

Comment: What neighbourhood? Moore or Von Neumann?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do

> 39 (Old: 38 (Old Old: 36))

I'm not sure that this is optimal, though:

> [image]
>  
>  (pawns are houses, I'm kind of lazy to edit pictures of houses in onto a grid)

Comment: It is still not optimal, buy you are nearly there!

Comment: Is it optimal now?